# Firefox bookmark toolbar custom folder icons?

Tags: firefox, bookmark

Is there an extension for current version of Firefox that enables you to change the icons of the folders in the bookmark toolbar? So far I've not found any, so I'm stuck with Waterfox Classic since it can still support the add-on Bookmark favicon changer 2.29 by Sonthakit Leelahanon.

Here is the screenshot of my bookmark toolbar:

[image]